# html email issue

Tags: email, outlook

The following displays the images I want in the row for my email.

However when I add an ahref tag around one of the images it pushes the last image off the row  when displayed in outlook 2010.

What am I doing wrong, why is the  tag adding to the width?

```
<center>
<table style="border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 640px;"     cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tbody>
<tr style="margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px;">
<td style="height: 50px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px;" valign="top"><a  href="yn"><img src="images/yn1.png" border="0" width="528" height="50" align="left" style="float: left; margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px;display: block;" />   </a><img src="images/yn2.png" border="0" width="42" height="50" align="left" style="float: left; margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px;display: block;" /><img src="images/yn3.png" border="0" alt="The NSW Nationals" width="17" height="50" align="left" style="float: left; margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px;display: block;" /><img src="images/yn4.png" border="0" width="42" height="50" align="left" style="float: left; margin: 0px; border: 0px; padding: 0px;display: block;" /><img src="images/yn5.png" border="0" width="11" height="50" align="left" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; float: left;display: block;" />  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue - I put my images inside a table with one image per cell.